# Shared Jar file between server and client -- NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, windows, debian

Im running a debian java server that needs to send and receive objects of type EventObject and PostObject (e.g serializable). These have been placed in a .jar file SharedModels.jar and are used both in client and on server.

When trying to compile on debian, I get the output

```
ServerThread.java:10: error: package Models does not exist
import Models.EventObject;
              ^
ServerThread.java:11: error: package Models does not exist
import Models.PostObject;
              ^
Database.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
                    ArrayList<PostObject> posts = new ArrayList<>();
                              ^
```

On the windows installation (Eclipse), using

```
 import Models.EventObject;
 import Models.PostObject;
```

works fine (including external Jar through Eclipse).

How do I go about making java understand that it is infact these classes I want to use on Debian?

I have added the location of the jar to my classpath in /etc/environment.

Is there perhaps a problem with the way the jar is structured? e.g. that it is composed of a Package that holds the two classes?

Regards and thanks in advance

EDIT: Made it compile fine, but when the method is called, the server doesn't recognize the class anymore. This is the output:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Models/PostObject
    at server.Database.getPosts(Database.java:101)
    at server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Models.PostObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I've understood this is  because JVM does recognize the class at compiletime but not during runtime.. OR something is wrong with classpath. Does the name of the actual .jar need to have any naming to fid the package contained within? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: How do you try to compile this on linux?

Comment: (1) This is exactly the sort of problem Maven and Gradle solve for you. (2) Use standard conventions for package naming--lowercase, and start with `com.example`.

Comment: compiled using javac file file file -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar

Answer (score 1):

No. Jars are portable, there is no difference between them. If they work on windows, they should work on linux, too.

Your error message shows also very clearly, that the problem isn't with bad jar, but that it doesn't exist in your classpath. Probably there is a trivial problem in your classpath setting, likely:

- Is your CLASSPATH syntax in your `/etc/environment` valid? On windows, it must be separated by `:`, while on linux there is a `;`.
- You included the *directory* of your jar into your classpath, and not the full path of your jar?
- `/etc/environment` is set up only in a login shell, did you log in / log out after that?

Anyways, you can give your `javac` a `-verbose` flag, which will show, where is it try to load your jars from.

Comment: Can you give an example of a classpath that uses 2 separate jars? This might be the issue.

Comment: solved by using javac compiling: `javac file1.java file2.java ... -cp myfirstjar.jar:mysecondjar.jar `.